# Creating index performance issue

Tags: oracle, indexing, ddl

I have to create an index on a table which has billion of records. at first i thought to create the index using **PARALLEL 8** option since the server is running with 8 cores.

Now the question is, nioce the index is created, primary key is created using that index. Can i add **NOPARALLEL** option?

I have tried this statement

```
ALTER INDEX PK_TABLE_NAME_ NOPARALLEL;
```

But it doesn't work. can someone suggest me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work just fine:

> SQL> create table t1
>   2  as
>   3  select rownum row_id
>   4  from dual 
>   5  connect by level <= 100;
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL> create unique index i1 on t1(row_id) parallel 8;
>
> Index created.
>
> SQL> alter table t1
>   2  add constraint pk1 primary key(row_id)
>   using index i1;
>
> Table altered.
>
> SQL> alter index i1 noparallel;
>
> Index altered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `ALTER INDEX myidx parallel 1;`

Source: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_parallel_create_index.htm